# Error while creating bootable Win 7 on USB Stick

Tags: boot, usb, windows-7, winusb

I would like to install a 32-bit version of Windows 7 on a 32GB USB stick by using WinUSB. 
After starting WinUSB with `gksudo winusbgui` from the terminal. I get an error when in the process of installing i386 grub.
Here I attach my error message.

[image]

Comment: You can use mkusb according to this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380

Comment: Have you tried booting on the USB ? Apparently grub.cfg has been installed and data has been sync'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Startup disk creator its a default tool in ubuntu for making bootable device or use dd command in terminal,
dd if=win.iso of=/deb/sdb (your USB stick path)
Or use unetbootin

[Unetbootin](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-linux-usb-from-linux/)